# About second-level domain names corresponding to nginx server blocks

Tags: nginx

There are 2 second-level domain names and 2 corresponding folders, like this:

```
domain name    folder
111.aa.com     /var/www/111.aa.com
222.aa.com     /var/www/222.aa.com
```

In `nginx.conf`,there are 2 server blocks,like this:

**#111.aa.com**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  111.aa.com;

    charset utf-8;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/111.aa.com;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}


    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /var/www/111.aa.com;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/dev/shm/php-fpm.sock;
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

**#222.aa.com**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  222.aa.com;

    charset utf-8;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/222.aa.com;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}


    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /var/www/222.aa.com;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/dev/shm/php-fpm.sock;
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Do two server blocks have to be required? If there are 100 second-level domain names, I have to write 100 server blocks, is it ok to write in one server block? How to write in one server block? Is there an example?
2. Writing in one server block and writing in respective 100 server blocks, which one is better?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the below:

```
server {
  server_name *.aa.com;
  root /var/www/$http_host;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ 404=@redirect;
  }

  location @redirect {
    return 301 http://aa.com;
  }
}
```

Since domains can not contain '..' or '/' Nginx will protect you from malformed domains that could be used to set a bad root location simply by rejecting invalid domain names, so security should not be much of an issue here.